# Java Https POST fails with connection timed out but works with Postman. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: java, ssl, https, connection

```
URL url = new URL(“My url”);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Base64EncoderDecoder encoder = new Base64EncoderDecoder();
String encoded = encoder.encodeToString(userName+”:”+password);
conn.setRequestProperty(AUTHORIZATION, BASIC + encoded);
conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
conn.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_TYPE, FORM_URL_ENCODED);        
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you check proxy setting if you are running with eclipse or any IDE?and remove connection timeout for testing.

Comment: vivekdubey am using intellij and i also removed connection timeout but not works

Comment: Can you check proxy setting

Comment: You are not able to connect the url may be proxy problem or typing problem in url.

Comment: I was using the office internet which might be using some proxies.So I tried using my mobile Internet through Hotspot and I was able to fetch the results.

This might happen due to some proxy preventing it from fetching the results.

Thanks

Comment: @vivekdubey can you tell me how to disable proxy so that i can access from my company internet itself

Comment: Talk to your team's network admin guys,they can help you

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void getEmployees()
{
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/

Answer (score 0):

I was using the office internet which might be using some proxies.So I tried using my mobile Internet through Hotspot and I was able to fetch the results.

This might happen due to some proxy preventing it from fetching the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem but mine was more of a typo. I mixed up between http and https.

Comment: Unless there is evidence of a typo in the posted question discussion your own typos are not particularly helpful.